# Can the following proof be written without using the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, axiom-of-choice

Claim: If $X$ and $Y$ are equinumerous sets, then so are $2^X$ and $2^Y$.

Proof: Since $X$ and $Y$ are equinumerous, there exists a bijection $f: X\to Y$. With this, we can construct a function $F: 2^X\to 2^Y$ as follows:

$$U\subset X \mapsto f(U).$$

To show that $F$ is onto, let $V$ be any subset of $Y$. Construct a set $E$ as follows:

$$X\supset U = \{f^{-1}(v) : v\in V\}.$$

It's easy to see that $F(U) = V$. To show that $F$ is one-to-one, let $U, E\subset X$ be distinct and $\textbf{choose}$ some $x\in U\,\triangle\, E$. WLOG, assume that $x\in U$. Since $f$ is injective, then $f(x)\in F(U)$ but $f(x)\notin F(E)$.

Comment: The last paragraph shows $F$ is one-to-one, not onto... Where is it you believe AC is being invoked? Choosing a single element from a nonempty set is not AC, it is existential instantiation.

Comment: If $U$ and $E$ are *distinct* subsets of $X$ then their symmetric difference is nonempty. You are not invoking the axiom of choice when you choose an element in a specific nonempty set. Choice is about an arbitrary collection of pairwise disjoint sets from which you wish to choose one element from each of them and put these choices into a set.

Comment: Just because you've written the English word "choose" does not mean you are applying the axiom of choice. If you were truly applying the axiom of choice, what you would have is an indexed family of nonempty sets, and you would then be forming a new set by choosing one element out of each set in that indexed family. So ask yourself: is that what you have? If so, can you name the indexed family of sets?

Answer (score 2):

There is no choice.

1. If $V \subset Y$, then $f(f^{-1}(V)) = V$. This is true for any *surjective* $f : X \to Y$.
2. If $f(U_1) = f(U_2)$, then $U_1 = f^{-1}(f(U_1))  = f^{-1}(f(U_2)) = U_2$. This is true for any *injective* $f$.